# opencart sort order for only a specific category

Tags: php, sorting, opencart, product

I have the default sort order for all categories by price low-high (`p.date_added ASC`) but for a specific category example "new products" I want the sort to be `p.date_added DESC`.

In `catalog/controller/product/category.php I have:

```
<?php class ControllerProductCategory extends Controller {
public function index() {
    $this->language->load('product/category');

    $this->load->model('catalog/category');

    $this->load->model('catalog/product');

    $this->load->model('tool/image');



    if (isset($this->request->get['filter'])) {
        $filter = $this->request->get['filter'];
    } else {
        $filter = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
        $sort = $this->request->get['sort'];
    } else {
        $sort = 'p.price';
    }

    if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
        $order = $this->request->get['order'];
    } else {
        $order = 'ASC';
    }
```

How can I make for the category "new products" the sort `p.date_added DESC`?

I have tried:

```
if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
    $sort = $this->request->get['sort'];
} else {
    $sort = 'p.price';
}

if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {  
    $sort = $this->request->get['sort'];
} else (isset($category_id) && $category_id == '109') {
    $sort = 'p.date_added';
}
```

But doesn't work.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you truly want to hard code this in to the controller, which is not something I would recommend, you can simply set the default sort depending on category.  One way to do it would be create an array with settings and refer to it in the logic:

```
$categorySorts = array(
    'default'   => array('sort' => 'p.price', 'order' => 'ASC'),
    '109'       => array('sort' => 'p.date_added', 'order' => 'DESC')
);

$default = $categorySorts['default'];   
if (isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
    $parts = explode('_', (string)$this->request->get['path']);
    $category_id = (int)array_pop($parts);
    if (isset($categorySorts[$category_id])) {
        $default = $categorySorts[$category_id];
    }
}

if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
    $sort = $this->request->get['sort'];
} else {
    $sort = $default['sort'];
}

if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
    $order = $this->request->get['order'];
} else {
    $order = $default['order'];
}
```

You could then add the your array for other categories in the future if you so desire:

```
$categorySorts = array(
    'default'   => array('sort' => 'p.price', 'order' => 'ASC'),
    '109'       => array('sort' => 'p.date_added', 'order' => 'DESC'),
    '110'       => array('sort' => 'p.sort_order', 'order' => 'DESC'),
    '111'       => array('sort' => 'rating', 'order' => 'DESC')
);
```

Personally, I would *not* go down this path.  It will make your life difficult and the lives of other developers who may be cursed with having to work on this site.  Instead, I advise you to dig a little deeper and create a **setting** for this in the admin panel.  It will be a lot more work but in the long run you will learn a lot and your website will not become a tangles mess of hardcoded rules.

Comment: I added the code in the controler after the line : f (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
   $page = $this->request->get['page'];
  } else {
   $page = 1;
  } and doesent work , it changes the id all categories to the default sort

Comment: did you change the array key to match the your category id?  It was only an example, since I can't magically guess what category ID you are using.  Since you've updated your question I'll assume it's 109.

Comment: yes i have edited the array for my specific category

Comment: I can verify this works.  Here is a working demo.  Price sorted descending: http://oc-demo-1564.zuma-design.com/phones-pdas.  Price sorted ascending: http://oc-demo-1564.zuma-design.com/phones-pdas.

Comment: i will paste my category.php in a sec

Comment: What is the url you are visiting when you go to your category?

Comment: i have addeed the code but on category id 109 its still the default p.price ASC

Comment: I modified the header controller and it works on categories but on my category id 109 is a subcategory.. , i tested on a category and it works, on my subcategory 109 doesen't work

Comment: I found the problem if its a subcategory you jsut put the "parrent id_subcat-id" in the array

Comment: Ok, I understand.  You should avoid using the full path because it can change depending on where it's linked from.  Take a look at the amended code in my answer now, I think this will work better for all subcategory regardless of URL structure.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is to check for the current category status, well, you should put the following before the first if:

```
$current_category_id = array();
$targeted_category_name = "new products";
$should_change = false; // this is a boolean telling us if the current category
                        // is what we want
if(isset($_GET['path']))
{
    $current_category_id = explode($_GET['path']);
}

foreach($current_category_id as (int)$cat)
{
    if($cat != 0)
    {
         $category_info = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($path_id);
         if($category_info['name'] == $targeted_category_name)
         {
            $should_change = true;
            break; // discontinue the loop
         }
    }

}
```

And then after you have added the above code, you should change the `sort` if-condition from :

```
if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
                $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
            }
```

To:

```
if (isset($this->request->get['sort']) && $should_change == false) {
                $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
}   
else
{
  $url .= 'p.date_added';
}
```

Though for having a dominance over your core and being able to easily update your opencart, you'd better to turn what your write (of course after seeing it works and contains no bug) into a module.